# Recently approved and live Facebook app and getting access token error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We've successfully authorized and completed a round trip with 2 accounts (both connected to the app) but now that we've opened up the app to the outside world, we are getting this error message response back after a successful (validated in users business integration settings) authorizations.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A1tNXOsDd1Jv_FLadSzpK9q"}}
```

The FB app is "Live" and approved and all App-Business settings are approved as well.

Comment: For what request …?

Comment: @CBroe this is the request: https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=540553756706712&redirect_uri=https://gmdy.co/ig-link&state=9a13f328-2d11-479f-a9e9-da62afa6a71f&scope=instagram_basic,manage_pages

Comment: That is only the redirect to the login dialog, and that does not involve an access token as input parameter. It must be some API call made after that.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. This is what is so confusing. Everything works as expected as long as the account authorizing through a link like the one above is connected to the app as developer. As an example, someone not connected to the app as a developer went through the authorization process and we received the error. We then added that account as a developer within the app and there were no generated errors and the user is now successfully authorized.

Why would developer accounts be successful and non-developer accounts fail?

Comment: What exact action / API call is giving this response?

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={}' \'&redirect_uri={}&state={}&scope=instagram_basic,manage_pages`

Comment: If you double-checked its the right app id etc., then perhaps file a bug report with Facebook.